# How to wrap a seperate component in ExtJS Class. Err : Class is coming undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, extjs

I created a new application in html and Java script. Where I am passing div id and creatinginput. My html and javascript code is given below

index.html

```
<head>
    <title>MyInput </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/MyInput.css">
    <script src="js/MyInput.js"></script>
</head>
    <body style = "height: 500px;">
        <div id="chart_line" style = "position: relative;"></div>
</body>
<script>
    var myCombo = new MyInput({
                "url": "data.json",
                "divID": "chart_line",
            });
</script>
```

Now it is going to javascript file `MyInput.js`

Here is my `MyInput.js`

```
MyInput = function(args) {
    var divID = args.divID;
    var div = document.getElementById(divID);
    var myTable = '<input type="text" id="myInput"   onclick = "openingList()" onkeyup="openingList()" style="width:30%;" >';
    div.innerHTML = myTable;
}
```

This is creating one input field for me.

Now I want to make this happen on ExtJS app. So I am trying to use wrap  into component. But This is getting failed. **Error is MyInput is not defined.**

My Code where I am trying to get this.

```
    {
        xtype : 'component',
        width: 40,
        height: 20,
        padding: 20,
        listeners :{
            afterrender : function(me,eOpts) {
                var tt = new MyInput.MyInput({ 
                    "url": "data.json",
                    "divID": "chart_line",
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Also befor using this I added my JS and Css file in app.json
I am trying to get this afterrender.
But here I a getting error. Can anybody suggest me how to make it correct.